# Cloud Foundry User Provided Service vars FROM NGINX

Tags: nginx, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I've a reverse proxy up and running in on bluemix using cloud foundry's node.js buildpack. However, I'm wanting to convert over to NGINX as my reverse proxy gateway. I think I've got everything figured out except how to pull variables from the CF UPS (User Provided Service) that holds my username / password.

I don't want to hard code it in the nginx.conf file. I've already been able to pull variables set in the manifest.yml, but obviously those are variables that aren't sensitive info, everything else needs to be pulled from my UPS.

Comment: You might look at using a `.profile.d` script.  These run prior to your application starting and give you a last minute chance to do something.  Maybe you could use this hook to update your config.

Comment: Thanks @DanielMikusa, I'll check this out and report back!